# CV Shaft Replacement Play

Tags: cv-joint, shaft

I'm replacing my CV shafts, 01 Grand Prix. I slid the new one onto the drivers side and locked it in place with the retaining c clip. The CV shaft is locked in, because I can't pull it back out.

But the CV shaft has a little in and out play where it sets into the transmission. Not the actual plunge joint on the CV shaft, I know that moves in and out. But where the splines of the CV shaft meet into the splines on the transmission. I can wiggle it in and out maybe like a quarter inch tops and it makes a little knocking sound when I do it.

I don't remember the old one having any play, but I didn't really check. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

little play is not a problem !!

if not confident, however, take the drive axle smoothly out of the transmission again and replace the retainer clip (snap ring) with a new known good (oem spare part number compliant). Take care not to damage the rubber seals in transmission while reinstalling process. Properly lubricate with manufacturer specified gear/transmission oil before starting engine.

Comment: Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGGu3JxVtKs&feature=youtu.be

Is that too much?  And I replaced the seal.

Comment: not clear, please ask local mechanic shops for free visual inspection. if you are a do-it-yourselfer, safely jackup your car and try to spin the wheel by hands in 9-3 and 12-6 clock position with car in gear and without gear. you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, they're called CV *joints* -- Constant Velocity joint(s).
The so-called "play" is actually *necessary*, and unless it's much more than half an inch on *your* yr/model car. It's just fine.

HTH

Comment: Indeed.  Seems like there is consensus then. Thanks!